# Where are the SharePoint 2010 project templates for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I checked the box to install the Office dev tools during the VS 2017 installation, but I see that only SharePoint 2013 and 2016 projects can be created. If I open an existing 2010 project and attempt to add an item, such as a list, no templates are available to me to choose.

It seems like 2010 no longer supported and I do not see a 3rd party option. Can we safely upgrade our 2010 solution to 2013, but still deploy it to 2013 in 2010 mode? Are there 2010 templates out there that Im just not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where are the SharePoint 2010 project templates for Visual Studio 2017?**

There is no SharePoint 2010 project templates in Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio 2017 supports only SharePoint 2016, SharePoint 2013 and Office 365.

**Can we safely upgrade our 2010 solution to 2013, but still deploy it to 2013 in 2010 mode?**

Yes, you can upgrade from 2010 to 2013 but your solution will no longer compatible back to be deployed on Sharepoint 2010.

**Are there 2010 templates out there that I'm just not seeing?**

No, As I above-mentioned it's not available in VS 2017, SharePoint 2010 project template is available in VS 2010 SP1, VS 2012, VS 2013, VS 2015. Meanwhile, if it's necessary to use VS 2017. in this case, you can install it over VS 2015 on the same machine.

For more details check

- [Visual Studio 2017 has landed](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/08/visual-studio-2017-for-sharepoint/).
- [Missing Office / SharePoint template in Visual Studio 2017](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/11/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/)